# HTML5 Lagging in Firefox

Tags: html, firefox

I'm working on my first HTML5 game. I use requestAnimationFrame to draw to the canvas, which is this:

```
window.requestAnimationFrame = function(){
    return (
        window.requestAnimationFrame       || 
        window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
        window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    || 
        window.oRequestAnimationFrame      || 
        window.msRequestAnimationFrame     || 
        function(/* function */ callback){
            window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
        }
    );
}();
```

I've only been using it in Chrome, but just now I tried it in Firefox. The game is laggy and not very smooth. Is this a bug, or is there a way I can fix this? Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Here's the game: http://jackscode.99k.org/comets/comets.html

Comment: Hard to say without seeing what the game is doing...  Do you have a link by any chance?

Comment: Hmm.  It's quite smooth in Firefox for me.  What Firefox version were you testing, if I might ask?

Comment: Weird, it works again. I think I caught a bug in Firefox.

Comment: Did you have Firebug open or something when you tested it the first time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see your code so it's hard to know what's the way to fix it but maybe if you are using a lot of settimeout in your game try using delta time it so much faster, works like a charm for me. Check out this guide how he uses it http://buildnewgames.com/sprite-animation/

Comment: What the heck...I just tried it in Firefox and it's working again. Maybe it was a bug?